# Fill a $1\times7$ table with $1$ type of $1\times1$ tiles and 6 different $1\times2$ tiles, using each type of tile as much as we want

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

(Note: I have asked this question before but I deleted it, as a user rightfully said it was a mess so I will try to open up a new clean page with this one.)

The problem is;

A rectangular table which is in the form of $1\times7$ is to be filled with $1$ type of $1\times1$ tiles  and $6$ different types of $1\times2$ tiles, how many different ways can we fill this table using each type of tiles as much as we want?

The complexity of this question is due to the fact that we can use as much as we want from each **type** of tile trying to fill a table of $1\times7$ width.

**My Attempts;**

I began thinking that I should find a general formula for $a_n$ which represents the possible variations for a place in form of $1\times n$ (1)

Let's say that we have started filling with one $1\times1$ block then there are $a_{n-1}$ possibilities to begin with (2)

Let's say that now we have started filling with a block in form of $1\times2$, then we have $a_{n-2}$ possibilities to begin with, but we can choose this block from $6$ others, so: $6a_{n-2}$ (3)

Then I have combined (2)&(3) and $a_n=a_{n-1}+6a_{n-2}$ (4)

We say that $x^n=x^{n-1}+6x^{n-2}$ (5)

The characteristic equation for (5) is $x^2-x-6$ (6)

The solutions for (6) are $x_1=3$ and $x_2=-2$ (7)

$c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_n=c_1(x_1)^n+c_2(x_2)^n$ (8)

Now I have tried to find $a_1$ and $a_2$ in order to find values for $c_1$ and $c_2$, they turn out to be $a_1=1$&$a_2=7$ (9)

I will skip the operations here for a little bit $c_1= \dfrac{3}{5}$ and $c_2= \dfrac{2}{5}$ (10)

So $a_n=\dfrac{1}{5}\left(3^{n+1}+2(-2)^n\right)$ (11)

Calculating $a_7$ will give me the result, (hopefully:) $a_7=\dfrac{1}{5}\left(3^8-2^8\right)$ (12)

Then what I get is not divisible by $5$ although the answer is supposed to be $1261$

I am strictly against using any calculator both in life and maths anytime and anywhere. And I have double,triple(-checked) my calculations, I think I might have made a mistake about the $a_1,a_2$ part, but I don't know. I would also appreciate any tactics that would help me solve these types of questions faster.

Thank you:)

Comment: $3^8-2^8=6561-256=6305$ is indeed divisible by five.  Dividing by five does indeed give you $1261$ as expected.  It appears as though you just made a miscalculation in the home stretch with your powers of three or two.  I see no other errors, good job!  As for a suggestion on how to possibly speed the process up, instead of using $a_1=1$ and $a_2=7$ as your seed values, you should use instead $a_0=1$ and $a_1=1$ as your seed values.  This will simplify calculations considerably for calculating $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: Thank you:),  so do we say that for a $1\times0$ table there are no fillings and having no fillings at all makes $1$ option? (Just to clarify it for myself)

Comment: No, there is one filling of the $1\times 0$ rectangle, namely, no tiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3^8-2^8$ is divisible by $3^2-2^2=5$. So you've made a calculation error.

(In the case $n=2m$ is even, $3^{2m+1}+2^{2m+1}$ is divisible by $3+2$.)

Your formula is correct. You would have had an easier time solving for $c_1,c_2$ if you started at $a_0=1$ and $a_1=1$.

---

A linear algebra approach, which works efficiently even when the roots aren't nice like $3,-2$, is to write out:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a_n\\a_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\6&1\end{pmatrix}^n\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Then you can compute $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\6&1\end{pmatrix}^n$ in $O(\log n)$ matrix multiplications. It's still a pain by hand, but for computer purposes, that difference is huge.

(The formula in terms of $(-2)^n$ and $3^n$ comes from diagonalizing this matrix. $-2$ and $3$ are the eigenvalues.)

Comment: Sorry if this seems like a copy of JM's comment above, but I was typing this answer into a now-deleted version of this question, then saw the new version/

Comment: It is ironic though that I didn't ise calculators and all that got me was a calculation mistake. Thank you:) (I really wouldn't know if I didn't post this question, I am so blind:)))

Comment: I don't see why we need $c_1$ and $c_2$ at all. Once we have $a_0=1$ and $a_1=1$ we can use equation (4) $a_n=a_{n−1}+6a_{n−2}$ and just proceed in a Fibonacci-like way.

Comment: Sure, you can do it that way, but the closed formula is more fun. @nickgard

Comment: @nickgard It would also be depressing to try finding a figure like  $1261$. Not even mentioning calculation mistakes could be made::))

Comment: There are ways to do these recursion calculations in $O(\log n)$ time using the recursion, and sometimes you don't get nice values like $3,-2$. It requires some linear algebra and the method of repeated squaring. (Repeated squaring can improve the time of your calculation too -
 $3^4=(3^2)^2, 3^8=(3^4)^2$.) @DenizTunaYalçın

Comment: Of course I didn't just jump to multiply 3 and 2 eight times and then subtract I used $(3^4+2^4)(3^4-2^4)$. But my problem is not about time it is about excitement I suppose , I somethimes don't see what is near me. Thanks for helping. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Yeah, the "efficiency" answer is really key for when the roots are not nice, like when you have $5$ types of $1\times 2$ tiles rather than $6$/